# how to automatically select jquery

Tags: jquery

this request may come a little silly for you.

Select 1

```
<select id="select1"  name="s1">
    <option id="1" value="Facebook and Twitter">Value 1</option>
    <option id="2" value="Google and Yandex">Value 2</option>
    .
    .
    .
</select>
```

Select 2

```
<select id="select2" name="s1">
    <option id="1" value="Okay">Value 1</option>
    <option id="2" value="No">Value 2</option>
    .
    .
    .
 </select>
```

How to select Okay when Facebook and Twitter are selected?

Comment: How do I update the query, add option values and id?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the name and id of both the dropdwon are same, make it different. And you can make selected a dropdown like:

```
$('#selectId').val(2);
```

It will make dropdown option having value 2 as selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#select2').val('No');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="s2" id="select2">
    <option value="Okay">Value 1</option>
    <option value="No">Value 2</option>
 </select>
```

Ex: It will make the dropdown `Value 2` i.e. `No` as selected

Answer (score 0):

**1st**: id must be unique .. so use class instead *don't duplicate id*

**2nd**: you need `.change()` event for `selest 1` and get its `.val()`

**3rd**: compare this `.val()` with value you have *Facebook and Twitter*

**4th**: you'll need to `prop("selected" , true)` *Okay* from `select 2` **OR** just use `.val('Okay')`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#select1').on('change', function(){
    var ThisVal = $(this).val();
    if(ThisVal == "Facebook and Twitter"){
      $('#select2').val('Okay');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="s1" id="select1">
    <option value="Facebook and Twitter">Facebook and Twitter</option>
    <option value="Google and Yandex">Google and Yandex</option>
</select>
<select name="s2" id="select2">
    <option value="Okay">Okay</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How do I update the query, add option values and id?

Answer (score 0):

1) `Id attribute` should be unique for each element

2) Use on `change` event to get the `current value` of first `select` if it's `Facebook and Twitter` then select `okay` in second otherwise select `No` like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#select2').val('No');
});

$(document).on('change','#select1',function(){

  if($(this).val()=='Facebook and Twitter'){
  
    $('#select2').val('Okay');
    
  }else{
  
    $('#select2').val('No');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="s1" id="select1">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="Facebook and Twitter">Value 1</option>
    <option value="Google and Yandex">Value 2</option>
</select>
<select name="s2" id="select2">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="Okay">Value 1</option>
    <option value="No">Value 2</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: How do I update the query, add option values and id?

Comment: give some explanation what you want ? @rootist

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
if($("[name='s1']").val()  == "Facebook and Twitter"){
      $('#select2 option[value=Okay]').attr('selected','selected');
    }
    
  $("[name='s1']").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Facebook and Twitter"){
      $('#select2 option[value=Okay]').attr('selected','selected');
    }
    else{
      $('#select2 option[value=No]').attr('selected','selected');
     }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="s1">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option id="1" value="Facebook and Twitter">Value 1</option>
    <option id="2" value="Google and Yandex">Value 2</option>

</select>
<select name="s2" id="select2">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Okay">Value 1</option>
    <option value="No">Value 2</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: How do I update the query, Are you looking at me again?

Comment: wait I am updating the answer

Comment: @rootist you can try now

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fkrumj

I want to set it up by ID, thank you for your understanding.

Comment: two IDs can not be same